# Scala Option doesn't handle null as expected

Tags: scala, syntax, pattern-matching, option-type

I don't understand the point of having an optional type in scala if the compiler doesn't infer the wrapping in this case:

```
f(null) // WHY ISN"T THE COMPILER DOING ANYTHING HERE!

def f(x : Option[String]) = {
// WHY DOES IT CRASH WHEN MATCHING "SOME(NULL)" !!
  val = x match {
    case Some(x) => s"blah blah append $x"
    case None => "" // !!! BOOM CRASH null scala.MatchError: null
    at
  }
  ...
  ...
}
```

What am I gaining if I now need to still check for null in the `f` function???

```
def f(x : Option[String]) = {
   // DON'T CRASH ?????
   if (x != null) {
      // now I can pattern match??? what is the point of the option???
     e match {... , case None => ??? what was the point of this?
   } else {
     e match { ...// BOOM ! CRASH AND BURN because "some" is NULL??? }
   }

}
```

Comment: `Option` is a simple data type, not a compiler magic. Good practice (followed by most of Scala libs) is to represent missing things with `None` and only use `null` for Java interop if not avoidable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing in Scala, in general, that disallows you to pass `null` around. An `Option[T]` is a contract with the caller, there is nothing compiler enforced about it. The contract for option says: "this value might no exist, so take that into account", it does not take into account that this value can be `null`. As with contracts, they may be breached, and we have to make sure to enforce them.

One way of dealing with this would be to add an extention to [WartRemover](https://github.com/wartremover/wartremover) which is a linter which runs as part of the SBT tool chain (there may be something like this already, not sure). This way, you can enforce options not being set to null at compile time instead of having them explode at runtime.

This isn't a "do it this way" answer because frankly, there isn't a good solution OOTB today. As long as references can be null, we'll have to deal with it. You have to be in charge of your code and make sure people use data types according to how they really should be used.

Comment: I thought the scala compiler would treat optionals the same way as the swift compiler does. This "option" is more of a "decorator" but has no real power to help me write safer code. I still am required to write all the regular boiler plate checking for nulls etc.

Comment: @AvnerBarr Although it doesn't have compiler enforcement behind it, I don't agree that you have to keep writing null checks everywhere, and by doing that you actually lose the power of the language. You have to make sure this convention is something that follows in the entire team writing the code base.

Comment: That isn't practical, especially if you don't know who is calling your code libraries. The right thing IMO is that the compiler should either NOT allow passing in null for those cases (since who knows what is happening behind the function) OR functions should not be allowed to use the value in the function until they have safely unwrapped it (ala swift)

Comment: @AvnerBarr I agree that this might not be optimal, but whoever is calling your code and passes `null` when an `Option[T]` is required doesn't deserve any "guarantees" from your library IMO.

Comment: In swift all types are NON-NULL by default . Only by wrapping them in a "option" can they even be considered to be "none" or "null"

Comment: @AvnerBarr I'm glad the language team had thought this through in Swift, but in Scala that isn't the case, we can only locally maximize what we have...

Comment: This saves the work of writing the tedious boiler plate checking for corner conditions (of null for instance) in the method.

Comment: Just found this to be an idiosyncrasy of scala. Didn't mean to open a full discussion. I thought maybe I was doing something wrong, but I now realize this is a language decision

Answer (score 1):

You could change `case None => ...` to `case _ => ...`, or add the latter after the clause for None if you want to handle null differently to None.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it is pass the value which can be null as an Option. e.g:

```
f(Option(null))
```

This will match your None case and not result in match error. The basic idea here is null is not supposed to be a scala construct but still even if you need to handle values which can be null, its better to wrap it in an Option and then pass around to make sure all functions interacting with it go on to work fine for normal and error scenarios. 
Also to understand in more detail how and why Option is implemented in this way you could read more on functional constructs such as Monads which give us the power of composition in functional programming. I found this blog to be a good primer to begin with:
http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html

Comment: If I have to explicitly write Option(null) I gain nothing . Might as well check for null in the method itself. The idea of an Optional type is to empower the compiler to enforce correctness and handling of those cases

Comment: Right. But I assume you have not written function for null values rather for non null values and need a mechanism to handle null values.

Comment: About this "i gain nothing", I want to disagree, Option(null) does not resault in branching of your code (at logical, not implementation level) and result is that complexity of the code is reduced